# Menu-Card Drupal 8 profile

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

Being quite new to Drupal, I've been tasked to work on an install profile for Drupal 8. Since I am not (and probably no one is), fan of installing additional stuff that's not needed, I'm trying to create a "menu-card" profile that allows to check modules for installation.

My first question would be if it's even possible to display a form during the install process **before** the actual installation and configuration process runs, as adding a form to an install task shows me this only after the install has run.

If the previous is possible, the next question is how do I make a form show before the install? If this isn't possible, would the best alternative be to simply use the composer.json file to add additional modules to the profile so these get installed when the `composer install` is ran?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [hook_install_tasks()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_install_tasks):

> ```
> /**
>  * Implements hook_install_tasks().
>  */
> function MYPROFILE_install_tasks(&$install_state) {
>   $tasks = [
>     ‘\Drupal\MYPROFILE\Form\ConfigurationForm’ => [
>     ‘display_name’ => t(‘Additional configuration’),
>     ‘type’ => ‘form’,
>     ],
>   ];
>   return $tasks;
> }
> ```

-- Snippet from [Medium](https://blog.ricovandevin.com/adding-a-custom-form-task-to-a-drupal-8-installation-profile-bdd4d01f1214)

Comment: This was what I tried previously, but this form only shows **after** the actual install has been done. I'm trying to figure a way out to display a form **before** the install takes place so there's no unnecessary modules that get installed, and the profile still is one single package that needs no modification.